# How to include Hidden Prefix @mention in Twitter client API for node (REST and Streaming API)

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, solr

I have added text and URL and image along with this I need to add `@username(@mention)`.

Please help me in doing this

```
var b64content = fs.readFileSync('/home/sivasaivarma/Day Users/sivasaivarma/personal/bigdata/images/leadoid.jpg', { encoding: 'base64' })
T.post('media/upload', { media_data: b64content }, function (err, data, response) {

    var params = {
        status: 'LEADoid filters media streams to find your target audience and then engage them within their own social post- https://leadoid.com/#!/home',
        media_ids: [mediaIdStr]
    }

    T.post('statuses/update', params, function (err, data, response) {
        console.log(data)
    })
}
```

Comment: Why is this relevant to Solr?

Comment: It seems like you have too many `}`.

Comment: } is not the issue i need one API for adding attachment-url that should add along with text(140) characters.

Comment: When i am adding Media/upload the URL is included in 140 characters.I need URL as suffix other than text(140) using twitter API